# Action not making use of cached dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I have a cached dataframe (which I can see in my spark UI). If I do a count() action it takes very little time as expected. Also if I visualize DAG I see that it makes use of the cached dataframe:

This code:

```
df_calls.count()
```

Gives this execution DAG:

[image]

(The little green circle means that it is a cached dataframe. So it means that the previous steps do not have to be executed, only the next steps)

Now the same for:

```
df_calls.map(row=>row.getString(10).toDouble).stats()
```

Gives this execution DAG:

[image]

No little green circle is present in the graph, so it does not make use of the cached dataframe, nevertheless the dataframe is still in memory. It seems that the data is being loaded again.

**What is happening here and why ?**

Comment: How do you conclude that the data is being loaded again?

Comment: In the second DAG, there is no green circle so no cached dataframe is used. The first step is 'textFile', so my best guess is, it is executed again.